# How to stop a LaunchDaemon in iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, xcode, jailbreak

I have a LaunchDaemon in my app. It fires perfectly on iPhone Start and keeps firing after a specific amount of time, but now i wanna know is there any way i can stop that launchDaemon and make it not fire if some condition is reached?

Comment: Depends how you've implemented it. Is it an NSTimer? Or something else?

Comment: Infact i want my `com.myLaunchDaemon.plist` inside `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` to not run if i change something in my app. That file Launches every specified instance of time and launches my LaunchDaemon, so i want that `.plist` file to not run my LaunchDaemon. Is there any way i can make changes to that file?

Comment: Try using the program "launchctl" -- I believe that you can do "launchctl stop com.myCompany.myLaunchDaemon" and that will stop it, you can run that via system() and such -- but of course I'm not fully sure :p.